# Compojure handler with an arbitrary number of URI parts?

Tags: clojure, compojure

Suppose I have URLs with the format:

- http://example.com/node/1
- http://example.com/node/stuff/1
- http://example.com/node/stuff/1/2
- ...

Is it possible to write a single handler that matches an arbitrary number of URI parts after http://example.com/node ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a wildcard `*` on the routes:

```
(GET "/node/*" request (handle request))
```

You can also define a regular expression over the variable part:

```
 (GET ["/node/:params", :params #"[^.]+.fn"] [params :as request] (handle params))
```

That sample will accept all `/node/something.fn` urls.

Compojure uses [clout](https://github.com/weavejester/clout) for the matching part you can read there more alternatives.